# CSS - load a content inside a div with either 100% relative or scrollable minimum size depending on div size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have searched a lot and couldn't find an exact solution for my problem.
basically i have a page, which can be loaded in any div. All the height and width inside the body is set relatively. When i load the page into a smaller div, i want it to have the 100% size of the current body (the body of the page i am loading into), and it should be loaded fully into the div without any cropping/autoadjusting, and it must be scrollable.

The only solution i came up with is hardcoding one single dimension inside the main page, but i do not want that, coz it should all be dependent upon the resolution of the screen and current zoom factor.

P.S i do not know what sample code i should give, nor what further details are required. please feel free to ask me for anything.

P.P.S i want to see if its possible to do without using js/jquery
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you could use viewport units `vw` and `vh`to set the size of your page equal in relation with the current viewport regardless of the `<div>` into which it's loaded.

> 1vw = 1% of viewport width
>
> 1vh = 1% of viewport height

for e.g.:

```
body{
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```

Browser support of there units @[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units)

Comment: Thanks buddy, that was exactly what i was looking for. Though the compatibility is an issue, ill find a solution to it.